# Find list of words from a range if words exits multiple times

Tags: excel, vba, find, range

I have a list of words in `Sheet1` I need to match one by one from `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A7500")` until the end of the `Range`. Whenever word is matched I need to do something with it in `Sheet1`. That word occurs multiple times in `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A7500")`.

Following code is Finding word only once. I dont understand where it is going wrong.

```
Sub XMAX()
Dim lrow As Long
Dim cel As Range
Dim oRng As Range: Set oRng = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A7500")
Dim oFoundRng As Range, oLastRng As Range


    lrow = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "f").End(xlUp).Row
    '''''''''''''''Sheet1'''''''''''''''
    For Each cel In Range("f4:f" & lrow)

        If IsEmpty(cel.Value) = False Then

            Set oFoundRng = oRng.find(cel.Value)

            Do While Not oFoundRng Is Nothing

                    If UCase(oFoundRng.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "ISAAC" Then
                        Range("X" & cel.Row).Value = "X"
                    ElseIf UCase(oFoundRng.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "YO" Then
                        Range("V" & cel.Row).Value = "X"
                    ElseIf UCase(oFoundRng.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "JAN" Then
                        Range("U" & cel.Row).Value = "X"
                    Else
                        MsgBox oFoundRng.Value
                    End If


                Set oLastRng = oFoundRng                    
                Set oFoundRng = oRng.FindNext(cel.Value)   'Getting Error(1004) here "unable to get findnext property of the range class" 
                If oLastRng >= oFoundRng Then               
                    Exit Do                                 
                End If
            Loop

        Else
        End If

    Next
```

Comment: what is the purpose of `If oLastRng >= oFoundRng Then`?

Comment: @DisplayName to `exit do` if all 'Cel.Value' have been found. I think `If oLastRng >= oFoundRng Then Exit Do` statement is wrong because its exiting `do loop` early

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
Set oFoundRng = oRng.FindNext(oFoundRng)
```

to

```
Set oFoundRng = oRng.FindNext
```

You are not searching for the word but for the range you previously found. You actually don't need to pass a value to `.FindNext` at all.

You also have to change this line

```
If oLastRng >= oFoundRng Then
```

to

```
If oLastRng.Row >= oFoundRng.Row Then
```

since the first line compares the values (which is not what you want to do since it will always evaluate to `True`). You actually want to compare the row numbers.

On another note, the following code snippet does not work:

```
If UCase(oFoundRng.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "ISAAC" Then
    Range("X" & cel.Row).Value = "X"
ElseIf UCase(oFoundRng.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "ISAAC" Then
    Range("W" & cel.Row).Value = "X"
```

This `ElseIf` will never be triggered since the condition is the same as the initial `If` condition.

You also don't need both of these statements:

```
Set oFoundRng = Nothing
Exit Do
```

They both achieve the same thing (breaking the loop), `Exit Do` does it more efficiently.

Comment: followed your suggestions, updated my question see now getting `Error (1004) unable to get findnext property of the range class`

Comment: I checked again and you don't acutally need to pass a value, try this line: `Set oFoundRng = oRng.FindNext`

Comment: further more I think `If oLastRng >= oFoundRng Then Exit Do` statement is wrong because its exiting `do loop` early(without going for 3rd time).

Comment: That's because `oLastRng >= oFoundRng` does not compare the row numbers, which is what you actually want. That line compares the values, which will evaluate to `True` since both cells have to contain the same string. Try this: `oLastRng.Row >= oFoundRng.Row`. I also added that to my answer.

Comment: For future reference, you might not want to call out someone else's code out as wrong before looking at your own code. That seems like a good way to stop people from wanting to help you.

Answer (score 1):

you may be after this (explanations in comments):

```
Sub XMAX()
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim oRng As Range: Set oRng = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A7500")
    Dim oFoundRng As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    With Sheets("sheet1") ' reference "Sheet1" sheet
        With .Range("f4", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "f").End(xlUp)) ' reference referenced sheet column "F" range from row 4 down to last not empty one
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) > 0 Then ' if there's at least one not empty cell
                For Each cel In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ' loop through referenced range not empty cells

                    Set oFoundRng = oRng.Find(what:=cel.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) ' always specify at least 'LookIn' and 'LookAt' parameters, or they will be set as per last 'Find()' usage (even from Excel UI!)
                    If Not oFoundRng Is Nothing Then ' if a match found
                        firstAddress = oFoundRng.Address ' store first matched cell address
                        Do
                            Select Case UCase(oFoundRng.Offset(0, 1).Value2)
                                Case "ISAAC"
                                    .Range("X" & cel.Row).Value = "X"
                                Case "YO"
                                    .Range("V" & cel.Row).Value = "X"
                                Case "JAN"
                                    .Range("U" & cel.Row).Value = "X"
                                Case Else
                                    MsgBox oFoundRng.Value
                            End Select

                            Set oFoundRng = oRng.FindNext(oFoundRng) ' search for next occurrence
                        Loop While oFoundRng.Address <> firstAddress ' exit do when hitting fisr found cell again
                    End If

                Next
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @IbneAshiq, any feedback?